# Volvo S60 T5 Auto gearbox replacement

Tags: automatic-transmission, volvo

My Volvo S60 T5's gearbox (aw55-50sn) has finally broken; it has a slipping third gear and possible clogged up solenoids in the valve body (due to it clonking into "D" mode).

I'm wondering if there's anyway I can add a different gearbox, maybe a newer version of the old one -an improved one-, or anything that would fit and be better? Or I must replace it with an exactly similar one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is only possible if the OEM has a newer version available for the same configuration. Generally if you want to do it on your own I think it is not possible

1. The mechanical design has to match the existing gearbox
2. The automatic transmissions have electronics which are controlled by an ECU and this ECU has to work for the new AT that you want to install. This is difficult to achieve
3. If you replace the ECU along with the transmission, again there is a problem. Today's ECUs communicate with each other via CAN bus. If you change the ECU, then the ECU CAN ids will change and the other ECUs will not be able to identify the new one thus generating DTCs